# Unable to build application a .NET project in Nant

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nant

Error Encountered

> error MSB3091: Task failed because "sgen.exe" was not found, or the .NET Framework
>   SDK v2.0 is not installed.  The task is looking for "sgen.exe" in the
>   "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the 
>   SDKInstallRootv2.0 value of the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework.    You may be
>   able to solve the problem by doing one of the following: 
>   1.) Install the .NET Framework SDK v2.0.
>   2.) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location. 
>   3.) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.

Installed .NET 2.0 SDK and also copied the sgen.exe (from:C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0 64bit)
to the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
Still not able to build.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, please try to set the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A` `InstallationFolder` key to the same path as the 2.0 Sdk path.

See [Task failed because "sgen.exe" was not found](https://dhvik.blogspot.sg/2007/11/task-failed-because-was-not-found.html) for some more details.

Comment: I tried this way ,unfortunately it didn't work.Still showed the same error!! 
Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following line in the .csproj file.

```
<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
```